# What is better to use: ADDTIME or plain INTERVAL to create time?

Tags: mysql

Here are two example queries:

```
SELECT NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE + INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
SELECT NOW(), ADDTIME( NOW(), '1:01:01' );
```

Is there any difference at all between these two queries? I mean, in performance or *best practice* uses ?

As far as I tested, the `INTERVAL` one seems to have slightly longer execution times.

***EDIT:*** The result for 100'000 loops almoust always came out something like this:

```
Interval:  8.5930590629578 seconds.
Addtime:   8.2951309680939 seconds.
```

```
SELECT NOW(), NOW() + 3661 SECOND;

Single interval:  8.3964569568634 seconds.
Interval:         9.1104879379272 seconds.
Addtime:          8.7062540054321 seconds.
```

***EDIT2:*** New examples:

```
SELECT NOW(), NOW() + 1 SECOND;
SELECT NOW(), ADDTIME( NOW(), '0:00:01' );
```

And the time results:

```
Single interval:  8.4611599445343 seconds.
Addtime:          8.7186510562897 seconds.
```

Does the `ADDTIME` parsing always slow it down so much, that the difference can been seen pretty well?

Comment: How did you determine that `INTERVAL` is slower?

Comment: I executed the queries 10000 times in loop and the average time for `interval` was a bit more then for `addtime` fo me.

Comment: That's an interesting result given that one might expect parsing of the time string (was `-0:15`, now `1:01:01`) to be the most costly difference between the two queries.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to test it on increasingly bigger tables? Running queries in a loop has too many variables imho.

Comment: @Jack I agree, but even with this method, the time results vary, but not the order of the *winners*.

Comment: I'm not sure how you benchmark but on my machine it only takes 0.04s to run it 100k times. But even in your case the difference is only 0.000003098s between the two methods. To be 100% sure what the difference is between the 2, you'll probably have to dig into the source code. One difference is that it needs another function call (addtime), since date_add(NOW( ), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) is also slightly slower.

Comment: Yeah, that's what @Nin said too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is if this is really a kind of performance gain you're looking for. Running this 100K times shows a difference of 0.02 sec. So if you run it 5 million times you save one second.

It's not fair to compare the two since the `interval` has to do 3 calculations (hour/minute/second). This will slow it down.

The `ADDTIME()` will have to parse the time which also slow it down.

Then if you're looking for performance use this:

```
 NOW() + INTERVAL 3661 SECOND
```

But even then you're saving milliseconds. If this is really the bottleneck of your application, then you've done a wonderful job :).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. I will test the performance gains if I use only seconds.

Comment: I updated the question with the new results. With seconds it seems that `INTERVAL` is now faster then `ADDTIME`.